# Clickable image in Windows 8.1 RT XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'd like to make an image button. With a image for the default status and a different image for the pressed status. With no other pressed highlights.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining your own style for `Button` control. I'll show you my example.

First, I have added two images to my project.

Normal.png
[image: normal button image]

Pressed.png
[image]

Then, I have definied new style in *App.xaml* file based on default `Button` style.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageButtonNormal" ImageSource="Assets/ImageButton/Normal.png" />
    <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageButtonPressed" ImageSource="Assets/ImageButton/Pressed.png" />
    <Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ImageButtonPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                Background="{StaticResource ImageButtonNormal}" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

As you can see, I have definied 2 `ImageBrush` objects for 2 button states. The look of the button is defined as `Border` with some content. We want to change the background of the `Border`. `VisualStateGroups` will handle this. I have added `Storyborad` in `VisualState` named `Pressed` to change the background of the `Border` just by switching `ImageBrush`. Simple!

The last thing you have to do is to apply the new style to your `Button` in XAML. I did it in *MainPage.xaml*.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user "PointerPressed" and "PointerReleased" events of the Image control to do that and change the Source property in each one. This will make Image flickers, so you can solve this problem by checking this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344161/image-flickering-in-windows-rt-app)